# Share "My Queries" from TFS

Tags: tfs

I have a few fairly involved work item queries saved in "My Queries" in TFS.  I don't want to make them Team Queries because we have too many of those already and most of the team doesn't care about these particular queries.

Is there a way to share these queries with the one other member of the team who is interested.

Is there a way to export them on my machine so that he can import them into his "My Queries"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your questions:

*Is there a way to share these queries with the one other member of the team who is interested.*

Yes

<strike>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822075.aspx</strike>

*Is there a way to export them on my machine so that he can import them into his "My Queries"?*

Yes

http://dhvik.blogspot.com/2009/06/handling-work-item-queries.html

Comment: Nice answer!  Note that if you only want to export 1 or 2 queries quickly, you can simply save them to a *.wiq file and attach them to an email.  Also, in TFS 2010 you can create subfolders underneath "Team Queries" and also control read/write permissions on each subfolder.

Comment: The link under "Yes" is a broken link.